# cannot read property of undefined/property not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My array is returning information and has data in it (not null) but yet it still errors saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date_appeal_received' of undefined" or "Uncaught ReferenceError: date_appeal_received is not defined.

I've tried:

```
console.log(result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received);  
console.log(result.parcel[1][date_appeal_received]);  
console.log(result.parcel[1]["date_appeal_received"]);
```

It will return the array completely if I just put `console.log(result);` but I need to put select property values into input boxes.

Here's the code:

PHP

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

    $parcel = $db->get_results("select * from parcels where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
    $comment_count = $db->get_var("select count(*) as count from comments where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);

    echo json_encode(array('parcel'=>$parcel,'comment_count'=>$comment_count));

}

?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "classes/get-apn-count-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
    type: "GET",
    data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(result){
            //do stuff here on success
            //console.log(result);
            $('#ViewComments').val('View ' + result.comment_count + ' Comments');
            if (result.parcel[0].apn != null){ $('#ParcelNumber').html(result.parcel[0].apn)
            } else { $('#ParcelNumber').html(" "); }
            console.log(result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received);
            /*if (result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received != null) { $('#DateAppealReceived').html(result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received);
            } else { $('#DateAppealReceived').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[2].date_appeal_received != null) { $('#BosMeetingDate').html(result.parcel[2].bos_meeting_date);
            } else { $('#BosMeetingDate').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[3].late_returns_date != null) { $('#LateReturnsDate').html(result.parcel[3].late_returns_date);
            } else { $('#LateReturnsDate').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[4].determination_notice_sent_date != null) { $('#DeterminationNoticeSent').html(result.parcel[4].determination_notice_sent_date);
            } else { $('#DeterminationNoticeSent').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[5].final_determination != null) { $('#FinalDetermination').html(result.parcel[5].final_determination);
            } else { $('#FinalDetermination').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[6].analysis_recommendation != null) { $('#AnalysisRecommendation').html(result.parcel[6].analysis_recommendation);
            } else { $('#AnalysisRecommendation').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[7].email_address != null) { $('#EmailAddress').html(result.parcel[7].email_address);
            } else { $('#EmailAddress').html(" "); }
            if (result.parcel[8].phone_number != null) { $('#PhoneNumber').html(result.parcel[8].phone_number);
            } else { $('#PhoneNumber').html(" "); }*/
    }
});
```

Array Result:

```
{
    "parcel": [{
        "parcel_id": "89415",
        "tax_year": "2012",
        "apn": "134-44-114",
        "vin": null,
        "owner_name": "BARRERA DIANE",
        "in_care_of": null,
        "mailing_address_1": "2402 W RIVIERA DR",
        "mailing_address_2": null,
        "city_state_zip": "TEMPE AZ 85282",
        "suite": null,
        "country": null,
        "initial_mail_date": "2012-05-11",
        "initial_return_date": null,
        "final_mail_date": "2012-07-13",
        "final_return_date": null,
        "reclass_mail_date": "2012-09-11",
        "bos_meeting_date": "2012-10-17",
        "date_appeal_received": "2012-09-18",
        "late_returns_date": null,
        "determination_notice_sent_date": null,
        "response_code": "No Response",
        "email_address": "dianefm@cox.net",
        "phone_number": "4807734925",
        "notification_type": null,
        "analysis_recommendation": "3",
        "final_determination": "A",
        "account": null,
        "revised_legal_class": null,
        "other": null,
        "change_address_request": null,
        "determination_notice_sent": null,
        "appeal_address_match": null,
        "situs_address_1": "2402 W RIVIERA DR",
        "situs_address_2": null,
        "situs_city_state_zip": "TEMPE AZ 85282",
        "owner_city": null,
        "owner_state": null,
        "owner_zip": null,
        "situs_city": null,
        "situs_state": null,
        "situs_zip": null,
        "penalty_amount": null,
        "penalty_mail_date": null,
        "penalty_appeal_recieved_date": null,
        "penalty_bos_meeting_date": null,
        "penalty_determination_notice_sent_date": null,
        "penalty_determination": null
    }],
    "comment_count": "9"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index in an array is `0`, not `1`. Your `parcel` array has only one entry in it: `result.parcel[0]`. If you want the `date_appeal_received` property from it, that would be:

```
console.log(result.parcel[0].date_appeal_received);
```

But your `success` function starts with this code:

```
$('#ViewComments').val('View ' + result.comment_count + ' Comments');
if (result.parcel[0].apn != null){ $('#ParcelNumber').html(result.parcel[0].apn)
} else { $('#ParcelNumber').html(" "); }
console.log(result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received); // <=== Problem line
```

The "problem line" above doesn't have any guard around it, and so it will always run. If `result.parcel` only has one entry in it, `result.parcel[1]` is `undefined`, and so trying to read the `date_appeal_received` property from it causes the error. Either check `result.parcel.length` to make sure it's `> 1`, or alternately since the entries in `result.parcel` are objects, you can use

```
if (result.parcel[1]) {
    // ...use result.parcel[1].whateverPropertyHere
}
```

If you're just trying to get at the other properties that are on the same object (`result.parcel[0]`) as `apn`, keep using `result.parcel[0]`:

```
console.log("APN: " + result.parcel[0].apn);
console.log("Date received: " + result.parcel[0].date_appeal_received);
// ...and so on
```

Or to save all that typing and redundant lookup:

```
var parcel = result.parcel[0];
console.log("APN: " + parcel.apn);
console.log("Date received: " + parcel.date_appeal_received);
// ...and so on
```

---

Side note:

This also works for getting the property from the first entry:

```
console.log(result.parcel[0]["date_appeal_received"]);
```

...since in JavaScript you can access a property either using dot notation and a literal property name (`foo.bar`), or brackets notation and a *string* property name (`foo["bar"]`).

Comment: @t-j-crowder I'm already using index zero. This is the second property I'm trying to retrieve.

`if (result.parcel[0].apn != null){ $('#ParcelNumber').html(result.parcel[0].apn)
            } else { $('#ParcelNumber').html(" "); }`

Comment: @maryjane9110024: You have this line in your `success` function, without any condition around it: `console.log(result.parcel[1].date_appeal_received);` That will cause the error.

Comment: @t-j-crowder even though there is data? I had a condition but I took it out so I could do a console.log on the property see if it was returning.

Comment: @maryjane9110024: There is data, but only in `result.parcel[0]`. On the line I quoted above, you're using `result.parcel[1].data_appeal_received`. `result.parcel[1]` is `undefined`, because you don't have a second entry in `result.parcel`. You're then trying to read a property from `undefined`. Either check `result.parcel.length` first, or do something like this: `if (result.parcel[1]) { ... }`.

Comment: @t-j-crowder OH I GET IT now... ok. I was thinking each individual property in the array was an item not the whole array itself. sorry! Thank you so much TJ!!